# ANDROID | Native crash | signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN)

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports, crash-dumps

I was unable to understand what could have caused this issue. Though it refers to RegexMatcher.
Does it mean, regular expression used in app may have caused this?
I am unable to reproduce this in devices. And it doesn't look like every-time issue.
Need support to understand what backtrace suggests?

**Devices where Issue is seen**
Huawei honor 10 Lite (HWHRY-H), Android 9
Huawei Mate 10 Pro (HWBLA), Android 9
Huawei Mate 20 Pro (HWLYA), Android 9
Huawei P20 Pro (HWCLT), Android 9
Huawei P10 Plus (HWVKY), Android 9
Huawei FIG-LX1 (HWFIG-H), Android 9
Huawei P20 Pro (HWCLT), Android 9

```html
**Error received from Google Play console:**
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000133d69  /system/lib64/libicuuc.so
  #01  pc 000000000019cf58  /system/lib64/libicui18n.so (icu_60::RegexMatcher::~RegexMatcher()+48)
  #02  pc 000000000019cfec  /system/lib64/libicui18n.so (icu_60::RegexMatcher::~RegexMatcher()+16)
  #03  pc 000000000002336c  /system/lib64/libjavacore.so (Matcher_free(void*)+68)
  #04  pc 0000000000094120  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.math.NativeBN.BN_copy [DEDUPED]+160)
  #05  pc 000000000018340c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry$CleanerThunk.run+76)
  #06  pc 000000000040c754  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (sun.misc.Cleaner.clean+164)
  #07  pc 00000000001daa0c  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.enqueueLocked+236)
  #08  pc 00000000001dab2c  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.enqueuePending+172)
  #09  pc 00000000001d7b04  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal+244)
  #10  pc 000000000015978c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run+76)
  #11  pc 00000000002c1038  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+72)
  #12  pc 000000000056ef88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
  #13  pc 00000000000d4204  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #14  pc 0000000000472fd4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #15  pc 0000000000474090  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+424)
  #16  pc 000000000049f684  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1120)
  #17  pc 0000000000083588  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #18  pc 00000000000241dc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

Comment: Hey were you able to solve this issue?